# Deploying a Profile Update via Tooling RESP API - INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY

Tags: tooling-api

I was wondering if anyway has ever been able to make updates to Profiles via the Tooling REST API?

I have recently built an application which creates CustomFields via the API, and I would then like to update profiles with permissions to those new fields. Fields are deploying fine using a POST to the CustomField resource, however I'm unable to update any profiles using a PATCH request as per the Tooling API documentation.

I have tried numerous examples of a profile update, but I am returned INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY - insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: 00eb0000000hlse.

Where the ID is the ID of my profile I'm trying to update.

I am posting my request to the URL:   https://eu2.salesforce.com/services/data/v33.0/tooling/sobjects/Profile/00eb0000000hlseAAA

Where eu2 is my instance and 00eb0000000hlseAAA is my Profile ID. That all works as expected, including for other resources (CustomFIeld, ApexClass etc).

My data payload - I have tried numerous examples:

**Example 1 - Update field permission**

```
{
    "Metadata": {
        "fieldPermissions": [
            {
                "field": "Account.Test__c",
                "editable": true,
                "readable": true
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Example 2 - Simple Update to Description**

```
{
    "Metadata": {
        "description": "Test description"
    },
}
```

I've tried different Metadata examples - including querying for the profile and then simply re-submitting it - but still receive the error.

I've tried different profiles, different fields and many different permissions.

Any help would be appreciated. I understand the Profile object has only been available since Winter '15 so I'm starting to consider it's just not supported as per the documentation.

I'm looking at you Andy Fawcett...

**EDIT**
As an FYI, the same concept works fine using the updateMetadata method from the Metadata API. That method being sending an update of a single field with permissions. My example code as follows (Python):

```
# Load WSDL
metadata_client = Client('http://fieldcreator.herokuapp.com/static/metadata-33.xml')

# Set up request URL
metadata_url = 'https://eu2.salesforce.com/services/Soap/m/33.0/ORG_ID'

# Set session settings
session_header = metadata_client.factory.create("SessionHeader")
session_header.sessionId = 'ACCESS_TOKEN'
metadata_client.set_options(soapheaders = session_header)

# Create field permission for new field
field_permission = metadata_client.factory.create('ProfileFieldLevelSecurity')
field_permission.field ='Account.Test__c'
field_permission.editable = True
field_permission.readable = True

# Create new profile and apply field permission
new_profile = metadata_client.factory.create("Profile")
new_profile.fullName = 'Test Profile'
new_profile.fieldPermissions = [field_permission]

# Deploy profile update
result = metadata_client.service.updateMetadata(profiles_to_update)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update `userPermissions` on Profile via REST API, you can remove `tooling` from the URL (and adjust body).

E.g.:

```
PATCH https://{YOUR_INSTANCE}/services/data/v46.0/sobjects/Profile/{PROFILE_ID}
{
    "IsSsoEnabled": false
}
```

I know it's a different case than in original question, but maybe somebody will find it useful.